# Resampling timeseries Data Frame for different customized seasons and finding aggregates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I am working on a huge timeseries dataset of following format:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('1990',end = '1994',freq='3H'),
                  'A': np.random.randint(low = 0,high=100,size=11689),
                  'B': np.random.randint(low = 10,high=45,size=11689) })
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date.astype(str), format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M',errors ='coerce') 
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date)
df.drop('date', axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

My aim is to first filter the dataframe according to the customized seasons: `winter (12,1,2)` (i.e. Dec, Jan, Feb), `Pre-monsoon (3,4,5)` , `monsoon (6,7,8,9)` and `post-monsoon (10,11)`. I am aware of `resample('Q-NOV')` function but it is quarterly only. As mentioned, I need to customize the months.
I have been able to do so by executing the following codes:

```
# DF-Winter
winterStart = '-12'
winterEnd   = '-02'

df_winter = pd.concat([df.loc[str(year) + winterStart : str(year+1) + winterEnd].mean() for year in range(1990, 1994)]) # DJF
    # used year and year+1 because winter season spans from an initial year to the next year.
```

```
# DF - Premonsoon
df_preMonsoon = df[df.index.month.isin([3,4,5])] # MAM
```

and so on.

**Problem**

I want to find the seasonal average values (every year and season) of my parameters `A` and `B` for my data period. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about grouping by df.index.year ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment . It works for other seasons except for the winter, which includes a month (Dec) of a year before.

Comment: You're right, good point. Maybe you should add that to the question.

Comment: @FObersteiner ,it is there in the code snippet ``` # DF-Winter
winterStart = '-12'
winterEnd   = '-02'

df_winter = pd.concat([df.loc[str(year) + winterStart : str(year+1) + winterEnd].mean() for year in range(1990, 1994)]) # DJF
    # used year and year+1 because winter season spans from an initial year to the next year.```

Answer (score 0):

Could something like that work for you:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

seasons_order = (
    'Winter',
    'Pre-monsoon',
    'Monsoon',
    'Post-monsoon',
)

dates = pd.date_range('1990',end = '1994',freq='3H')

def define_seasons(month):
    if 1 <= month <= 2:
        return 'Winter'
    if 3 <= month <= 5:
        return 'Pre-monsoon'
    if 6 <= month <= 9:
        return 'Monsoon'
    if 10 <= month <= 11:
        return 'Post-monsoon'
    if month == 12:
        return  'Winter'

def define_seasons_year(date_to_convert):
    if date_to_convert.month == 12:
        return date_to_convert.year + 1
    else:
        return date_to_convert.year

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': np.random.randint(low = 0, high=100, size=dates.size),
        'B': np.random.randint(low = 10, high=45, size=dates.size),
        'season': pd.Categorical(
            dates.month.map(define_seasons),
            categories=seasons_order,
            ordered=True
        ),
        'season_year': dates.map(define_seasons_year),
    },
    index=dates
)

print(df)

seasonal_average_values = df.groupby(['season_year', 'season']).mean()
print(seasonal_average_values)
```